# BIRT running the same query twice

Tags: mysql, birt

BIRT is running the same query twice. First time w/ "set limit = 1" and then w/ "set limit = default". This is very inefficient.

```
2018-02-23T14:18:44.107184Z    4 Query  SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=1
2018-02-23T14:18:44.107184Z    4 Query  select id from game where id >= 1
2018-02-23T14:18:44.125145Z    4 Query  SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT
2018-02-23T14:18:44.125145Z    4 Query  select id from game where id >= 1
```

When we use parameters in the SQL, it is even worse as the first query does not have any parameter filled.

```
2018-02-22T20:18:28.159070Z   52 Query  SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=1
2018-02-22T20:18:28.159070Z   52 Query  select id,username from customer where id = '' and username != ''
2018-02-22T20:18:28.161104Z   52 Query  SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT
2018-02-22T20:18:28.161104Z   52 Query  select id,username from customer where id = 123123 and username != 'dasdsadsa'
```

I tried it with BIRT 4.5/4.6/4.7 and mysql jdbc driver 5.1.35/5.1.45.

I already tried to add cacheResultSetMetadata=true to the connection string but it didn't help.

Any ideas?